# 投稿ページが複数ある場合のデータベースの設計について聞きたいです。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

おそらく初歩的な質問ですが、よろしくお願いします。現在、ユーザー登録して、複数のページが存在して、各ページにコメントを投稿できるサービスを作っています。
ページの構造としてはA市、B市,C市という風にいくつかの市があり、それぞれに治安、景観、人柄、交通の便など市を評価する軸となるページを用意し、それぞれにコメントがつけられるようにしたいのです。この場合、データベースは一つでよろしいのでしょうか？
まだ初心者なもので、一つのデータベースにまとめると、たとえば治安と景観のコメントが一つのデータベースに混在し、さらにそれがどの市のものなのかもわからなくなりそうな気がしています。
どのように解決すればいいでしょうか、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

１アプリケーション１データベースにするのが普通です。

質問のようなアプリケーションであれば、「投稿」の種類ごとにテーブルを分けるか、１つのテーブルで投稿の種類を区分するようなカラムを作る形になるでしょう。

０から自分の作りたいアプリケーションに取りかかるより、まずは入門書やRailsチュートリアルなどの資料を参考にして一通りのアプリケーションを作ってみるとよいと思います。

Comment: なるほどありがとうございます引き続き頑張ります